# jqplot custom zooming mannually or set zoom level

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am in the process of developing a line chart for vehicle time table. In the chart X-axis showing the Time & Y-axis showing the Stops.I have given zooming functionality in the graph by using **plugins/jqplot.cursor.js**

Here As per the requirement in page load itself the graph should be zoomed-in 50%. Or can I call the zoom function manually with particular zoom level?

Any solutions to my queries are highly appreciated.

Thanx

Pradeep

Comment: JQPlot permits to select a zone to zoom. Which zone must be zoomed? Center? If yes, you could play with the XY min-max ranges

Answer (score 0):

The big issue with playing with XY min-max ranges is that you can't zoom out because technically you are at a 100% zoom.
Unfortunately, I did not find any way to manually set a particular zoom level using jqplot.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.